# \\server\users\name doesn't show all contents

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

With Win7 Home Premium computers when I browse or map to `\\server\Users\myname` only 3 folders are shown - *Documents, Music, Pictures* - yet when looking at that directory from the local console there are 22 sub-folders. Why aren't they all available over the network, and more importantly, how do I fix it so I can see them all?

The use case is to map H: (home) to my profile directory on the desktop computer from my laptop, so I don't have to try and keep them in sync. Both are running Windows 7 Home Premium, desktop is 64bit, laptop 32.

UPDATE: On the desktop `C:\Users` is shared and *myname* is a member of the Administrators group on both machines (and uses the same password). *Advanced Sharing >> Permissions* shows *Everyone* and *server\Administrators* as having Full Control.

Comment: tried registry tweak for enabling access to `\\server\C$`, no go (but didn't reboot) http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-mapping-to-hostnamec-share-on-windows-vista/

Comment: Are they included as shared folder? Do you have permission to open them from connections else than local console?

Comment: @Robuust, Yes `C:\Users` is shared and `myname` is a member of the Administrators group on both machines (and uses the same password)

Comment: Are the folders you don't see using inherited values? Or do those folders also have administrator roles added in them?